# no viable alternative at input error in Python :: Cassandra session.execute() statement

Tags: python, cassandra

I need to insert few records in a table in Cassandra, and I wish to pass the column name using ".format() function. But I am facing below error. Can anyone let me know the issue here?

```
session.execute(
    """
    insert into test.student({})
    values(%s)
    """.format(mylist[0])
    [59])
```

Error:

```
File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2240, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute
File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 4198, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result
cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 
[Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'">
```

Answer (score 0):

In the insert statement the driver is unable to identify the values to replace, try with:

```
session.execute(
"""
insert into test.student({0})
values({1})
""".format(mylist[0], 59)
```

the column that will be updated will be the first item of your variable `mylist`, with the value 59

There are multiple examples using the python driver at https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/tests/integration/standard/test_query.py.